# Make Total In 1 column

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-6

[query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5U65q.png)
Column

Controller

```
$gapok = DB::table('gaji')->where('gaji.pegawai_id','=', $gaj->pegawai_id)->groupBy('gapok')->get();
$tunjab = DB::table('gaji')->where('gaji.pegawai_id','=', $gaj->pegawai_id)->groupBy('tunjab')->get();
$bpjs = DB::table('gaji')->where('gaji.pegawai_id','=', $gaj->pegawai_id)->groupBy('bpjs')->get();
$bpjs = DB::table('gaji')->where('gaji.pegawai_id','=', $gaj->pegawai_id)->groupBy('bonus')->get();
$total = $gapok + $tunjab + $bpjs + $bonus;
```

Thanks All, I can Do with This Code

```
$gapok = DB::table('gaji')->where('gaji.pegawai_id','=', $gaj->pegawai_id)->sum('gapok');
$tunjab = DB::table('gaji')->where('gaji.pegawai_id','=', $gaj->pegawai_id)->sum('tunjab');
$bpjs = DB::table('gaji')->where('gaji.pegawai_id','=', $gaj->pegawai_id)->sum('bpjs');
$bonus = DB::table('gaji')->where('gaji.pegawai_id','=', $gaj->pegawai_id)->sum('bonus');
$total = $gapok + $tunjab + $bpjs + $bonus;
```

Comment: Would you like only the total number or a column?

Comment: Check out the docs on aggregates: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#aggregates

Comment: total number...

Comment: can't use count T_T,give me an example with count :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this?

```
$total = count($gapok) + count($tunjab) + count($bpjs) + count($bonus);
```

But if you want all the values, try something like this:

```
$users = DB::table('users')->whereNull('last_name')->union($first)->get();
```

for example:

```
$gapok = DB::table('gaji')->where('gaji.pegawai_id','=', $gaj->pegawai_id)->groupBy('gapok')->get();
$tunjab = DB::table('gaji')->where('gaji.pegawai_id','=', $gaj->pegawai_id)->groupBy('tunjab')->union($gapok)->get();
$bpjs = DB::table('gaji')->where('gaji.pegawai_id','=', $gaj->pegawai_id)->groupBy('bpjs')->union($tunjab)->get();
$bpjs = DB::table('gaji')->where('gaji.pegawai_id','=', $gaj->pegawai_id)->groupBy('bonus')->union($bpjs)->get();
```

But you can check your query, it may be wrong. Note:

```
  $gapok = DB::table('gaji')
             ->where('gaji.pegawai_id','=', $gaj->pegawai_id)
             ->select('gaji.pegawai_id', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
             ->groupBy('gaji.pegawai_id')
             ->get();
```

Comment: $gapok = DB::table('gaji')->where('gaji.pegawai_id','=', $gaj->pegawai_id)->sum('gapok');
                    $tunjab = DB::table('gaji')->where('gaji.pegawai_id','=', $gaj->pegawai_id)->sum('tunjab');
                    $bpjs = DB::table('gaji')->where('gaji.pegawai_id','=', $gaj->pegawai_id)->sum('bpjs');
                    $bonus = DB::table('gaji')->where('gaji.pegawai_id','=', $gaj->pegawai_id)->sum('bonus');
                     $total = $gapok + $tunjab + $bpjs + $bonus;